# UDPEcho or C Code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, sockets, udp

Im making an iPhone application that sends commands and retrieves data through an UDP connection.

I have a question, since my [previous question did not get answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313278/receiving-data-from-udp-server-on-ios-app-is-not-working-from-linux-server-but) and I was not able to fix it by now I am looking for two other ways to implement an UDP connection.

1. UDPEcho
2. C code

Which one is better [advantages/disadvantages] and which one is easier or recommended to implement it into an iphone application?

Comment: that ur old question wasn't answered might be due to the fact that u only poorly tagged it. Just 30 views in 2 days were triggered.

Answer (score 1):

[UDPEcho](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009660-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) already set up the iOS project for you, so unless you need to port your app to other platforms afterwards, that would give you a headstart compared to C code.

Comment: Yeah I dont need to port the app to other platforms. So you think its easier because all the setup is all ready done? I dont know why, but I find the explanation of Apple not always that clear. But maybe its because I look at it too difficult. 

It just looks like C is easier. But your advising the UDPEcho :) Did you work with it? and how was your experience with it?

Comment: In fact I've more experience in fact using UDP with just C. I agree that Apple documentation is woefully useless, bordering on malice, but it's always handy to have a working xproj to start with. I briefly looked at UDPEcho and it seems like a timesaver, but if you have a preference for just C, then use whatever floats your boat.